# Shapable terrain in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sandbox, terrain

I want to make a shapable world (and maybe also procedurally generated), but I don't know how to make it via script.

There are a few examples whom I have a few questions about:

**Minecraft**

It is easy to make a procedurally generated shapable world from cubes, but I don't know how to make it optimal. Does unity strong enough the handle a lot of cubes?

**Landmark**

In this game you can shape the world and it uses Unity like terrain. It's is similar to Minecraft but it's not as cubic. (So when you dig in the ground, you dig ~like in real life. So you don't dig cube by cube like in Minecraft)

Is it possible to shape the terrain runtime?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What platform do you plan to run on?

Comment: This question has been asked 1000 times.  There are ***a number of*** minecraft starter kids and voxel starter kits on the asset store, or, you can even find free software around (look on the Unity forum etc).  (It is inconceivable you can program it yourself from scratch, it would take 2-3 years.)  Just google "minecraft kits for Unity".  This sort of general question is for gamedev.com, not here

Comment: Yes it's very possible but as @JoeBlow highlights it needs a lot of learning. Even though there are assets in the store, I'd recommend learning first, e.g. this guy here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3  What he does is landmass generation, but that's part of the "control over your terrain" you want, so this is the lobby for doing such thing

Comment: Tudvari there are huge numbers of this question asked, just google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is easy to make a procedurally generated shapable world from cubes

Short answer, no it is not easy. You would have to use some type of noise to generate a heightmap (like voxel noise, [here's a blog tutorial](http://studentgamedev.blogspot.no/2013/09/unity-voxel-tutorial-part-3-perlin.html))

> [Is] unity strong enough the handle a lot of cubes?

No, on it's own unity will not handle the amount of cubes needed for a minecraft clone very well. Statistically speaking you will never be able to see all 6 faces of a cube, so rendering all 6 is wasteful. Also, each cube will have it's own collider which will quickly clutter. Also you do not need to render a cube if it is blocked by other cubes. All this requires complex optimization code to make it run efficiently as you are modifying the terrain and moving through the world.

> Is it possible to shape the terrain runtime?

Yes, here's some code I stole from [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/120707/can-unity-apply-heightmaps-ingame.html):

```
function Start()
{
    terrain = GetComponent(Terrain);
    var nRows = 50;
    var nCols = 50;
    var heights = new float[nRows, nCols];
    for (var j = 0; j < nRows; j++)
        for (var i = 0; i < nCols; i++)
            heights[j,i] = Random.Range(0.0,1.0);
    terrain.terrainData.SetHeights (0,0,heights);
}
```

and here's the documention on `TerrainData.SetHeights()`
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetHeights.html

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Unity built in terrain's heightmap: [TerrainData.SetHeights](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetHeights.html). You will need to define some kind of a brush like draw crater, depends on your needs.